# iostream comparision in boost and stl

Tags: c++11, boost, stl, boost-asio

As I referred,

```
stlp_std::ostream  //stl lib call for io stream
boost::archive::text_oarchive //boost call for io serialization using archive
```

Could anyone please clarify me what is the use of serialization through archiving ?
Is both the call refer same functionality ?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What is unclear about serialization?

Comment: Kindly make me to understand , How does archiving related to serialization ?

Comment: What library do you think `text_oarchive` comes from..?

Comment: `#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>`
I am using this as the header for `text_oarchive`, Am I Correct ?

Comment: That's the header it comes from, yes, but the _library_ is [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/doc/archives.html). ;-]

Answer (score 1):

The distinction is actually a bit of FAQ. It's well addressed in the documentation of the Boost libraries. All the bolding and capitalization in the below quotes is original, not by me:

In **["Archive concept"](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/doc/archives.html)**:

> *The existence of the `<<` and `>>` suggests a relationship between archives and C++ i/o streams. **Archives are not C++ i/o streams**. All the archives included with this system take a stream as an argument in the constructor and that stream is used for output or input. However, this is not a requirement of the serialization functions or the archive interface. It just turns out that the archives written so far have found it useful to base their implementation on streams.*

There's even a section on that **[in the "Rationale":](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/rationale.html#archives)**

> #### Archives are not streams
>
> Archive classes are **NOT** derived from streams even though they have similar syntax rules.
>
> - Archive classes are not kinds of streams though they are implemented in terms of streams. This distinction is addressed in [[5]](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/doc/bibliography.html#5) item number 41.
> - We don't want users to insert/extract data directly into/from  the stream .  This could create a corrupted archive. Were archives derived from streams, it would possible to accidentally do this. So archive classes only define operations which are safe and necessary.
> - The usage of streams to implement the archive classes that are included in the library is merely convenient - not necessary. Library users may well want to define their own archive format which doesn't use streams at all.

Comment: Archives are not C++ i/o streams - 
Now I am very clear
Very very Thank you @sehe.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is *reversible* conversion of a data structure to a linear sequence of characters. C++ iostreams do not provide any reversibility, boost archives do.

An archive is a place where you store documents for later retrieval. Boost archives store serialized data structures for later deserialization.